# Check InnerException in System.TypeInitializationException thrown by an external code frame

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, inner-exception

Using Visual Studio 2012 Express, how can I check the `InnerException` when a `System.TypeInitializationException` is raised from an external code frame. The debugger breaks due to the exception, however not at any code line. It gives the following message:

```
No Source Available
The call stack contains only external code.
Thi thread is stopped with only external code frames on the call stack. External code frames are typically from framework code but can also include other optimized modules which are loaded in the target process.
```

And then gives the call stack, See below:

[image]

I would set a try-catch block, but I don't know where in the code this happens. How can I inspect the `InnerException` at this point? Is there another way to go about finding what's  up?

Comment: Look in the locals window.

Comment: you could try narrowing the problem, by inserting multiple try-catches where you think the problem is happening, set a breakpoint at all catches and run the application. When it breaks, try decreasing the size of the try catch, and try again.

Comment: @SLaks, For what? The entire stack contains code that the OP hasn't written.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg That's unrealistic for a big multi-threaded code base

Comment: @Jonathan I didn't know, that you application was that big.

Comment: have you tried with the intellitrace? or catch it with Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException

Comment: @SLaks the Locals window is empty

Comment: @BrianS: For `($exception)`

Comment: Try disabling Just My Code.

Comment: @SLaks where do I disable Just My Code?

Comment: On the Tools menu, choose Options.
In the Options dialog box, open the Debugging node and then choose General.
Clear Enable Just My Code

Answer (score 1):

Repro code for such an exception where the stack trace looks exactly like yours:

```
class Program {
    static Program() {
        throw new Exception("kaboom");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
    }
}
```

You should use the Exception Assistant that pops up when the exception is thrown.  Click on "View Detail":

[image]

Comment: No Exception Assistant pops up for me. Could this be because I'm using VS12 Express?

Comment: No idea.  Tools + Options, Debugging, General, ensure that the "Enable the exception assistant" option is checked.